# How to load info from 3 Ms-Access tables to 1 DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I want to load names and some information from 3 Ms-Access tables.
This is my code :

```
Sub loadnames()
    Try
        Dim dt As DataTable = New db_con().selectdata( _
              "SELECT famille1.ID, famille1.Article, famille1.quantité FROM famille1;")

        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i + 1, dt.Rows(i)(0), dt.Rows(i)(1), dt.Rows(i)(2), dt.Rows(i)(3), dt.Rows(i)(4), dt.Rows(i)(5))
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

I want to load some information from tables ( *famille2* & *famille3*) but with one code to one DataGridview.

Comment: Create a query that joins your _famille_-tables and use that as source for your gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very crude, and Im definately sure there are better ways of doing this... BUT... :)... here's a straight forward way to extend on your code...

Create a datatable for each of the queries and populate the datagrid from each of them.

```
Sub loadnames()
    Try
        Dim dt As DataTable = New db_con().selectdata( _
              "SELECT famille1.ID, famille1.Article, famille1.quantité FROM famille1;")

        Dim dt2 As DataTable = New db_con().selectdata( _
              "SELECT famille2.ID, famille2.Article, famille2.quantité FROM famille2;")

        Dim dt3 As DataTable = New db_con().selectdata( _
              "SELECT famille3.ID, famille3.Article, famille3.quantité FROM famille3;")

        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i + 1, dt.Rows(i)(0), dt.Rows(i)(1), dt.Rows(i)(2), dt.Rows(i)(3), dt.Rows(i)(4), dt.Rows(i)(5))
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To dt2.Rows.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i + 1, dt2.Rows(i)(0), dt2.Rows(i)(1), dt2.Rows(i)(2), dt2.Rows(i)(3), dt2.Rows(i)(4), dt2.Rows(i)(5))
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To dt3.Rows.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i + 1, dt3.Rows(i)(0), dt3.Rows(i)(1), dt3.Rows(i)(2), dt3.Rows(i)(3), dt3.Rows(i)(4), dt3.Rows(i)(5))
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Hth
Chicken

Answer (score 0):

Your Select string should look something like this...

```
Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT ID, Article, quantité FROM famille1" &
                               "UNION ALL" &
                               "SELECT ID, Article, quantité FROM famille2" &
                               "UNION ALL" &
                               "SELECT ID, Article, quantité FROM famille3;"
```

Then when you get your DataTable

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```